# How can i chain a list of operations in my calculator?

Tags: javascript

```
let Display_ = document.getElementById('display'); // The display which shows all the numbers clicked.


// NOTE these functions are called by the operate() function, which takes an operator and two numbers as its parameters and checks the operator against an if statement and calls a correct arithmetic function accordingly.

function add(a,b) {
    Display_.textContent = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
}
function sub(a,b) {
    let Array = [a,b];
    let Result = Array.reduce((acc,current) => acc-current);
     return Display_.textContent = Result;
}
function mul(a,b) {
    let Array = [a,b];
    let Result = Array.reduce((acc,current) => acc*current);

     return Display_.textContent = Result;
}
function div(a,b){
    let Array = [a,b];
    let Result = Array.reduce((acc,current) => acc/current );
     return Display_.textContent = Result;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

// The operate function is called when the = button is pressed.

function operate(operator,a,b) {
    if (operator == "+") {
        add(a,b);
    }
    if (operator == "-") {
        sub(a,b);
    }
    if(operator == "*") {
        mul(a,b);
    }
    if( operator == "÷") {
        div(a,b);

    }
}


let _save, save_, save; // LHS operand,RHS operand, The arithmetic operator.

let NUMBERS = document.querySelectorAll('.n'); // selecting all the buttons with numeric values

// for each button we are adding a click event which basically displays the buttons value on the display.

NUMBERS.forEach((n) => {
    n.addEventListener('click' , function () {
        Display_.textContent += n.textContent;
    })
})

// ---------------------------------------


let CLEAR = document.getElementById('clear'); // getting the clear button

// clear when clicked, flushes the display

CLEAR.addEventListener('click', function () {
    Display_.textContent = null;
})

// ---------------------------

let OPERATORS = document.querySelectorAll('.operator'); // getting all the operators except for =

let G_OPERATE; // will use this to store the value of the arithmetic operator clicked so that later on we can send it to operate() and call an appropriate function accordingly.

// for each operator button, we are adding a click event which will basically set the value of _save(LHS operand) to the value on the display and then flushing the display so that when the user inputs/selects another number, that number will be stored in save_(RHS operand) when the equal operator is clicked.  

OPERATORS.forEach((o) => {
    o.addEventListener('click' , function () {
       _save = parseFloat(Display_.textContent);
       Display_.textContent = null;
       G_OPERATE = o.textContent;

    })
})

let EQUAL = document.getElementById('equal'); // getting the equal button.

EQUAL.addEventListener('click' , function () {
    save_ = parseFloat(Display_.textContent); // upon clicking, store the RHS operand in save_ (RHS operand)
    operate(G_OPERATE,_save,save_);
})
```

Hello. This is a calculator project from the Odin project. I have tried my best to make the code as readable as possible for StackOverflow by adding comments to each line possible. The only thing that i want as of now is string of operations to work.

Whenever the user presses an *operator* button(**doesn't include =**), whatever the display shows will be stored in a variable and the display will be flushed. after that the user inputs another value and that value is stored upon clicking the equal button and then with the equal button there is an event listener which basically calls the operate() function which calls an appropriate arithmetic function and returns the final value to the display.

Comment: You will have to return object that has operators from operator functions